# How did my collaborators' commits find their way into my branch?

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, git-push, git-commit

I am new to Git and still learning about it. I want to push my local branch commit to remote. I have

1. created a local branch `Task1004` and done some work,
2. committed all the changes,
3. run `get fetch` and `git pull origin development`
4. run `git rebase development`.

Now I want to push my changes but, when I use `git log`, I see all other commits which have been pushed by other developers on branch `development`; for instance, one of my own commit and 3 commits by my collaborators.

When I run

```
git push origin Task1004
```

all 4 commits are pushed to `Task1004`, which will be later merged with `development`.

What is the reason of this and what should I do to push only my commits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you rebased `Task1004` to `development`. If you rebase your `Task1004` branch to `development` (or merge it with `development`), your collaborators' commits will become part of your branch's history; there's no way around that (see my detailed explanation below). If you don't want that to happen, simply do not rebase to or merge with `development`.

On the other hand, why wouldn't you? Keeping up to date with a remote branch that's more stable than the one you're currently working on is good practice.

---

Here is a reconstruction of what happened. I'll call the `development` branch "dev", for conciseness. Let's assume that, at the beginning, your repo's history looked like that:

```
A [HEAD,dev,origin/dev]
```

After creating and checking out the branch called `Task1004`, you got

```
A [HEAD,Task1004,dev,origin/dev]
```

After you did some work, staged the changes and committed, your repo's history looked as follows:

```
A [dev,origin/dev]
 \ 
  B [HEAD,Task1004]
```

You then pulled (fetch + merge) the `dev` branch, on which your collaborators had created a few more commits in the meantime. Your repo then looked something like that:

```
A -- C -- D -- E [dev,origin/dev]
 \ 
  B [HEAD,Task1004]
```

You then rebased `Task1004` to `dev`, and ended up with

```
A -- C -- D -- E [dev,origin/dev]
                \ 
                 B' [HEAD,Task1004]
```

So now, because of that `git rebase`, the commits of your collaborators (C, D, and E) became part of branch `Task1004`'s ancestry. Therefore, it's normal that those commits show up in the log of that branch.

To finish, you pushed your `Task1004` branch to remote, and ended up with

```
A -- C -- D -- E [dev,origin/dev]
                \ 
                 B' [HEAD,Task1004,origin/Task1004]
```

Comment: thanks u, i got the answer of why it happens.. ..i use <code>git rebase development</code>...every time when i push to development it push others commits also  ..i just want to push my single commit ..no other commit which i have rebase with development..how can i solve that ?

Comment: @ChaitsiPatel As I wrote in my answer, if you rebase your `Task1004` branch to `development` or merge it with `development`, your collaborators' commits will be part of your branch's history; there's no way around that. If you don't want that to happen, simply do not rebase to or merge with `development`.

Comment: how should we fix it once we have others commit showing up on our branch? I did pull `dev` again and merge `dev` onto my `Task1004` branch and pushed again and now my collaborator's commits are gone, but why is that the case? thanks!